# Consuming a WCF service without having any service contract or data contract reference during compilation

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have been googling for quite some time now but cannot find a definite answer.

I **want to consume a wcf service, whose address will be provided at runtime**.

The user will enter the address of the wcf service at runtime.

**During compilation I have no idea of the service contract or the data contract or the endpoints of the wcf service.**

Could someone please let me know how to achieve this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

This was the original idea behind [UDDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration). Before making a call, the client would query some central repository and obtain the address, contracts, and bindings of the service endpoint. It would then use this information to assemble and call the channel.

Some ESBs work on this principal - the call to UDDI can also be logged centrally, so an audit is kept of all service calls made within the enterprise.

Microsoft implemented it's own [UDDI server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730814.aspx) which can be integration into SCOM for this purpose.

Comment: It seems that UDDI is obsolete. In my scenario the WCF services are already hosted and I have no control over the service(service or data contract) and I simply want to consume them. So I need to discover the schema returned so that I can provide a mapping to my actual business entities.

Comment: It's true UDDI is rarely used, but it's not obsolete. The standard still exists and using it would be a valid decision until an alternative is proposed.